# how to reindex dspace 5.2?

Tags: dspace

I added new field pagesNo in dublin core. I made that metadata field searchable. But when I was not able to reindex dspace. dspace index-update and dspace index-init  are not working. Secondly my search and homepage is not displaying. I get following error:

```
An internal server error occurred on http://code1.dogears:8080/jspui:

Date:       12/08/15 17:36
Session ID: E38E9E4CD2EA2ED9FDD10438DF02769A
User:       Anonymous
IP address: 127.0.0.1

-- URL Was: http://localhost:8080/jspui/internal-error

-- Method: GET
-- Parameters were:


Exception:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:127)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.dspace.app.webui.discovery.SideBarFacetProcessor.process(SideBarFacetProcessor.java:73)
        at org.dspace.app.webui.discovery.SideBarFacetProcessor.process(SideBarFacetProcessor.java:61)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:120)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: If you are using the default installation of DSpace 5.2, it is using solr, you should instead run `dspace index-discovery -b`.

Comment: It looks to me like the errors you're having are unrelated to the change you made. Did accessing /jspui work before you added the metadata field? Also, what is in your index.jsp file at line 127 (as referred to in the stack trace)?

Comment: dspace index-discovery -b gives null pointer exception